# Doctrine Update query with a sub-query

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1, doctrine, dql

I'm trying to execute a query, similar to the following one, using doctrine dql:

```
Doctrine_Query::create()
              ->update('Table a')
              ->set('a.amount',
                    '(SELECT sum(b.amount) FROM Table b WHERE b.client_id = a.id AND b.regular = ? AND b.finished = ?)',
                    array(false, false))
              ->execute();
```

But it rises a Doctrine_Query_Exception with the message: "Unknown component alias b"

Is restriction about using sub-queries inside the 'set' clause, can you give me some help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you want to update all rows from the table? This kind of update query may result in different data in the `amount` column, depending on the ordering used for the update. (I assume `a` and `b` are aliases for the same table. Is that correct or they are two different tables?)

Comment: Hi @ypercube, no a and b are aliase to diferent tables. Table a is for clients and table b is for it's accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a restriction on this but I remember fighting with this sometime ago. I eventually got it working with:

```
$q = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection();
$q->execute("UPDATE table a SET a.amount = (SELECT SUM(b.amount) FROM table b WHERE b.client_id = a.id AND b.regular = 0 AND b.finished = 0)");
```

See if that does the trick. Note that automatic variable escaping doesn't get executed with this query as it's not DQL.

Comment: Yes that did the trick. i've found this solution few minutes after posting the question. Anyway, that is a solution for me, Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Years later but may help.

#### Yes ]

If you need/want/have to, you can use the *Querybuilder* to execute an *update query* having a sub select statement, instead of using directly the underlying connection layer.
The idea here is to use the QueryBuilder twice.

- Build a select statement to compute the new value.
- Build the actual update query to submit to the database, in which you will inject the former select DQL, as you expected in order to issue a single database request.

#### Example ]

Given an application where users can sell objects. Each transaction involves a buyer and a seller. After a transaction ends, sellers and buyers can leave a review on how went the deal with their counter part.
You might need a **User** table, a **Review** table and a **Transaction** table.
The User table contains a field named *rating* which will hold the average rating for a user. The Review table stores a transaction id, the author id (who submitted the review), a value (from 0 to 5). Finally, the transaction contains a reference for both the seller and the buyer.

Now let's say you would like to update the average rating for a user after a review has been submitted by the counter part. The update query will compute the average rating for a user and put the result as the value of the `User.rating` property.
I used the following snippet with *Doctrine 2.5* and *Symfony3*. Since the work is about users, I makes sense to create a new public function called `updateRating( User $user)` inside the *AppBundle\Entity\UserRepository.php* repository.

```
/**
 * Update the average rating for a user
 * @param User $user The user entity object target
 */
public function updateRating( User $user )
{
    // Compute Subrequest. The reference table being Transaction, we get its repository first.
    $transactionRepo = $this->_em->getRepository('AppBundle:Transaction');
    $tqb = $postRepo->createQueryBuilder('t');
    #1 Computing select
    $select = $tqb->select('SUM(r.value)/count(r.value)')
        // My Review table as no association declared inside annotation (because I do not need it elsewhere)
        // So I need to specify the glue part in order join the two tables
        ->leftJoin('AppBundle:Review','r', Expr\Join::WITH, 'r.post = p.id AND r.author <> :author')
        // In case you have an association declared inside the Transaction entity schema, simply replace the above leftJoin with something like
        // ->leftJoin(t.reviews, 'r')
        // Specify index first (Transaction has been declared as terminated)
        ->where( $tqb->expr()->eq('t.ended', ':ended') )
        // The user can be seller or buyer
        ->andWhere( $tqb->expr()->orX(
            $tqb->expr()->eq('t.seller', ':author'),
            $tqb->expr()->eq('t.buyer', ':author')
        ));
    #2 The actual update query, containing the above sub-request
    $update = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
        // We want to update a row
        ->update()
        // Setting the new value using the above sub-request
        ->set('u.rating', '('. $select->getQuery()->getDQL() .')')
        // should apply to the user we want
        ->where('u.id = :author')
        // Set parameters for both the main & sub queries
        ->setParameters([ 'ended' => 1, 'author' => $user->getId() ]);
    // Get the update success status
    return $update->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
}
```

Now from the controller

```
            // … Update User's rating
            $em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->updateRating($member);
            // …
```